# What is the word?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image: Images that somehow have to do with the word]

Edit: I realized that people are somewhat distracted from the actual word. **Most** of the images are just supposed to represent a simple word. People search for what the picture means (For example: People guess "Blackjack" instead of "Dealer" for the first image) instead of what the picture shows. The next time I create a puzzle I will make sure people get on the right track (or I will make a puzzle that is as complicated as people expect this one to be)

Edit 2: How long should I wait until I post the correct answer?

Hint 1:

> ... Dealer, ... Neck, ... Flip, Life xyz ...

Comment: For those of you who don't know, the woman at the bottom right is [**\*\*POSSIBLE SPOILER\*\***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linda_Perry).

Comment: If some time has passed with no progress on the puzzle, it is generally nicer to give your potential solvers some hints and some more time to let them come up with the solution themselves.  See also **[How long should I wait before providing the answer to my riddle?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2799/30633)** and the answer there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it is

> Bottle

The four pictures are:

one:

> Bottle dealer or bottle service

two:

> Bottleneck

three:

> [Bottle flip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottle_flipping) (that silly youtube trick that I used to think was stupid until people started eating tide pods).

four:

> [Life in a bottle](http://www.metrolyrics.com/life-in-a-bottle-lyrics-linda-perry.html) (A song by Linda Perry).

Comment: Congratulations! You are right!

Answer (score 2):

So we have

> Black Jack, a Black Back, and a guy doing the Back Jack

So I guess

> She wants Jack Back.

;-)

To be more precise, upper right is a

> black neck

Well, looking at her career, she maybe just wants

> her life back.

Clarification:

> Given that she probably wouldn't want any Jack, rather a Jill, and that she has a Jill but needs a life, I guess she wants her life back. So In any case, the suggested answer here is "back".

---

EDIT (new guesses):

OK, if nobody comes up with stuff, I'll throw out a few more wild guesses, just what came in mind, suggested solution in italics.

I'll start with some stuff that didn't work for me, maybe someone can get another idea off it:

Since that flipping sucker looks like second life to me, I got the idea to look for her second live disc (maybe the casino guy would fit the title), turns out, there is no such thing.

I tried to find the article about her in Life magazine. Couldn't find any, nor anything around that fact.

There is a Linda magazine, but it's from the Netherlands and doesn't seem related to this riddle.

There is a Perry magazine, but it's about real estate deals on Malta, seems even less related, although they have a display of vertebrae at the prehistoric site and cave museum.

1)

> guy is a dealer, neck needs a healer, jerk's no appealer, she writes for a *squealer*

2)

> this guy looks gay, that photo is an x-ray, flipper causes dismay, a life in *disarray*

3)

> Loser, bruiser, poser, *boozer*

4) let's say the pictures mean

> player, discs, flip, Linda Perry (although missing the big [LIFE]),

then the solution could be

> *in flight*, (although those are two words) since that's her only album on vinyl as far as I could find (a vinyl is the only kind of disc type for commercial releases you need to flip in the player)

not really happy with any of these, though, but that's what I got so far.

Comment: ... or probably [Jack Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_black).

Comment: So what word exactly is your guess? Black or Back?

Comment: @Finni: I added a clarification

Comment: Ok, it is wrong though. I added a clarification to the puzzle, too.

Comment: @Finni: I had no doubt about that, or I would have been more precise in the first place :-)

Comment: Could be "4 non blondes", although I'd need to just assume for the x-ray one.

Answer (score 2):

Could the word be...

> **double**, as in "double dealer", "double image", "double flip", and "double life"? Not sure how Linda Perry fits into it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly

> INSURANCE

because

> DEALER

,

> INJURY (whiplash?) or maybe just HEALTH

,

> ACCIDENT

and

> LIFE Cover

?

Comment: How would Linda Perry fit in then?

Comment: It wouldn't matter who she was in this case? Which I guess means I'm wrong :o)

Comment: Yep, I like the idea though

Answer (score 1):

And a final third <s>attempt</s> guess:

> RECORD (or MUSIC) INDUSTRY

because you have

> DEALER, DISC(s), SPIN, and PRODUCER

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone find the word. The images are:

> - A casino dealer. The game is [blackjack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack).
> - An [X-ray image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_image). I also found out that the image is also associated with [degenerative disc disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerative_disc_disease).
> - A guy doing a [back flip](https://www.google.com/search?q=back+flip&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwjzrL7HpeTYAhWF1ywKHd3ICXIQ_AUICygC).
> - The logo of [Life magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_(magazine)) and the picture of [Linda_Perry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linda_Perry)

Answer (score 0):

Option two, word is:

> BOND

because:

> Casino Royale ... possibly "Dr, no!" ... Sky fall ... and [don't know].